nslookup command crashed on ubuntu20.04 built on 07/24/2024
we are building custom ubuntu20.04 image for few months now. Everyday we pickup focal packages from ubuntu repo to build our root-fs.
In today's build 07/04/2024  nslookup command crashing.
nslookup
netmgr/netmgr.c:232:isc__netmgr_create(): fatal error: libuv version too new: running with libuv 1.44.2 when compiled with libuv 1.34.2 will lead to libuv failures
Aborted (core dumped)
ii  bind9-dnsutils   1:9.18.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.1        amd64        Clients provided with BIND 9

ii  dnsutils                     1:9.18.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.1        all          Transitional package for bind9-dnsutils

ii  libdns-export1109                     1:9.11.16+dfsg-3~ubuntu1          amd64        Exported DNS Shared Library

ii  libuv1:amd64                          1.44.2-1+ubuntu20.04.1+isc+1      amd64        asynchronous event notification library - runtime library

uname -a
Linux nsappliance 5.4.0-189-generic #209-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 7 14:05:13 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I see bind9-dnsutils version got updated today. any help on this appreciated.

How are you using 1.44.2 of libuv1? The official repos don't have that version for 20.04, it's currently 1.34.2-1ubuntu1.5. Are you using some PPA?

thanks muru.that may be the reason 1.44.2 is picked up as part of dist-upgrade command that we run which has non standard eternal repo.

@VivekSedhumadhavan if you're mixing repos then you should get nslookup from the repo you got libuv 1.44 from.
